# how can i retrieve the location the user selected through flutter google places autocomplete screen so i can create route?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

i tried just "p" and through my display route function but i printed out the output to the log and all i got was "p is instance of 'Prediction' "

```
 child: TextField(onTap: () async{
     Prediction p = await PlacesAutocomplete.show(
                context: context, apiKey: kGoogleApiKey,
                language: "en", components: [new Component(Component.country, "mw")]
              print("+++++++$p");

                                            displayRoute(p);


                );
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass **Prediction** object as a parameter to the following function and get **latitude**,**longitude** and **address** of the **selected location** inside it.

```
void _getLatLng(Prediction prediction) async {    

    GoogleMapsPlaces _places = new 
       GoogleMapsPlaces(apiKey: API_KEY);    

    PlacesDetailsResponse detail =
        await _places.getDetailsByPlaceId(prediction.placeId);    

    double latitude = detail.result.geometry.location.lat;
    double longitude = detail.result.geometry.location.lng;
    String address = prediction.description; 
}
```

For Further details check this [article](https://medium.com/@usamasiddiqui766/google-places-autocomplete-suggestions-in-flutter-469fd65f4492).